# I got a error when running a github project in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

[DCGAN](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow)

when I run the project , i got the error.

```
ValueError: Variable d_h0_conv/w/Adam/ does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

the part of code is below.

the optimizer:

```
d_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(config.learning_rate, beta1=config.beta1) \
            .minimize(self.d_loss, var_list= self.d_vars)
        g_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(config.learning_rate, beta1=config.beta1) \
            .minimize(self.g_loss, var_list= self.g_vars)
```

the variables:

```
self.d_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'd_' in var.name]
        self.g_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'g_' in var.name]
```

the operation:

```
def conv2d(input_, output_dim,
           k_h=5, k_w=5, d_h=2, d_w=2, stddev=0.02,
           name="conv2d"):
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        w = tf.get_variable('w', [k_h, k_w, input_.get_shape()[-1], output_dim],
                            initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input_, w, strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1], padding='SAME')

        biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [output_dim], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        conv = tf.reshape(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases), conv.get_shape())

        return conv
```

Environment:

**ubuntu14.04 , python2.7 tensorflow 0.12**

Thank you for help.
I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were were running the command to train the network after pulling the data.

I was able to clone the project, pull the image data sets, and run the training command using Python 3.5 on Ubuntu w/Tensorflow 0.12.  The commands are only slightly different

(e.g. python3 main.py --dataset mnist --is_train True vs python...)

I know this project support python 2.7 but you able to run the project using python3?

Comment: I want to know what cause this problem."Variable d_h0_conv/w/Adam/ does not exist" do you understand "adam"?

Comment: Adam is the default name given in the scope... so that variables can be reused within the computational graph.

Comment: The word Adam is the default name added to your graph by the AdamOptimizer

Comment: I find the variablies "Variable d_h0_conv/w/"

Comment: but I don't find the variablies "d_h0_conv/w/Adam/"

Comment: This is due to a change in TensorFlow.  Can you try doing a fresh pull?  The GitHub history shows this change: https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/commit/6ddd8a469c68d75abcbcd42d4d9dfc44f94debc0 that fixes the issue you are having with TF 0.12

Comment: It looks like you were just a bit ahead of the project team and they did a few updates to support TensorFlow 0.12.  If you do a fresh pull (or update your fork from the master), you should be good to go.

Comment: Did pulling that last change answer your question?

Comment: I can run the project in tensorflow 0.11